# Snakemake task fails on SLURM without error - how to debug?

Tags: slurm, snakemake

I try to run multiple tasks via SLURM using `snakemake --slurm -j 200`. Some of the SLURM jobs fail but I cannot find any error message. `snakemake` prints the following:

```
...
[Thu Sep 28 10:25:04 2023]
Error in rule optimize_network:
    message: SLURM-job '783028' failed, SLURM status is: 'FAILED'
    jobid: 142
    input: data/input/some_input.nc
    output: output_42.nc
    log: .snakemake/slurm_logs/rule_optimize_network/783028.log (check log file(s) for error details)
    shell:
        
        python -c 'import my_func; my_func()'
        
        (one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!)
...
```

In some cases, the log file mentioned here does not exist at all, sometimes it does not contain any error message. The tasks are all instances of the same rule with different parameters for the wildcard. When I run only one of them, e.g. `snakemake --slurm -j 200 output_42.nc` it works, so it seems not really related to the rule or to the parameter.

Is there anyway I could debug this further? How does snakemake submit the jobs? Can I print the SLURM commands executed? How can I find the error message?

Answer (score 1):

I would start by confirming you aren't immediately running into resource issues.  You can use [reportseff](https://github.com/troycomi/reportseff) to look at resource usage of lots of slurm jobs.

That will help with jobs that are submitted and fail without writing anything to the log.  However, the fact that some jobs aren't producing logs indicates an error during job submission.  For jobs that fail without logs, do they get a slurm job id?  My best guess is you are running against the maximum job submissions for a given queue; e.g. the sysadmins only allow 150 short jobs for a given user, above that the job submission fails.  Check your slurm config to confirm.  If that's the issue, you can limit your total jobs or add a custom resource per queue to stay below the limits.

Those are my typical slurm issues; that and not creating the slurm output directory prior to job submission (but snakemake should do that automatically).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there good reason why snakemake cannot report such errors directly? If the submission fails, I expect a specific error by sbatch or one which can be somehow retrieved via SLURM.

Comment: Not sure.  Based on how snakemake reports other shell errors it seems like error message forwarding just isn't implemented.  It's probably to limit some commands from spewing lot's of information to stderr and swamping the user.  May be worth opening an issue if you can confirm this is an sbatch error.

Comment: Hmm actually I have seen other error messages from sbatch, like an invalid runtime.